# Set parental controls on an Admin account

Tags: permission, macos, parental-controls

So this is a strange question, but I'm starting to get really organized and stuff, and I want to make sure my computer shuts off at 10:00 (I'm in high school). The problem is, being the only admin on my computer, I would be able to get around it. Is there any way I can have my parents choose a password to enter, without me knowing it, and make it so I can't bypass it?

Comment: FYI, your edited question should probably be an entirely new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - the admin user is the way that the system detects which accounts can modify a parental restriction either once or permanently.

You'll need to not use or (have) an admin account or come up with some other social contact like setting up a recurring alarm that you voluntarily obey when the time comes to cease computing.

Scheduling an automatic shut down would also work to give you some notice that it's time to be done and the system would take action unless you over ride the power down.

Just head to the energy saver preference pane and establish a schedule for the system to shut itself on and off would be my recommendation for a user with admin privileges yet wanting a reminder to keep certain hours.